# How to send notification whenver new news arrives in android?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a news app using NewsAPI, where i fetches data using retrofit and show them in my app. I want to implement the notification feature i.e, whenever the api have some new news(new data), i want to show notification in my android app. This notification should work whether the app is running or closed. How can i do that?

I know that notification API is helpful for handling notification but it only works when my app is running. If app is closed it will not able to check new news and send notifications. I have to handle this from backend, How can i acheive this.
I am new to android, any rough idea will be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you want to [notify users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your usecase, you should use [Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging?hl=en) in your backend and app.
If you use FCM, you can send notification messages that are displayed to your user.
Also, you can send data messages and determine completely what happens in your application code whether your app is running or closed.
When you implement FCM in android app and backend, Please be aware that [the message handling logic can be different with the FCM message payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive?hl=en).
Even with FCM, your app may be handle notification differently depending on whether it is running in the Foreground or Background.